# Irobot create 2 C# connection

Tags: irobot-create, roomba

My department recently purchased Irobot create 2. We want to recreate the code from the Csharp create 2 driving Tether program to use as a base for our intro to computer science course. Currently the code we are using to talk to the Irobot is http://www.robotappstore.com/Knowledge-Base/How-to-program-Roomba-for-NET-developers/23.html. Not sure if the irobot is getting the commands as well as if the serial port is making a connection. We are using Visual Studio 2012 as the programming environment. Any recommendation and or input would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Robotics.StackExchange Chris!  Can you clarify your question?  It is a little unclear what you are asking.  What have you tried, what is not working?

Answer (score 2):

Please see the last page of the [Open Interface Spec](http://www.irobot.com/~/media/MainSite/PDFs/About/STEM/Create/create_2_Open_Interface_Spec.pdf?la=en).  There are some notable changes between the Create 2 and the old Create.  For example the default baud rate changed.